# Xamarin.Android always hangs on "Installing"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

Having trouble on multiple devices when trying to debug from `Xamarin.Android` the Xamarin IDE hangs every time on "Installing".

Answer (score 0):

Something to do with multiple accounts on the device causing issues. Instead of uninstalling the app from settings, uninstall from ADB (even if it doesn't seem like it is installed).

```
adb uninstall <package-name>
```